# In order to pray , do I have wash to wash "everything" that is touched with semen(wet /dry) or madhiy?

Tags: salat, hadith, sharia, islamic-basis, masturbation

I masturbate on a regular basis. I am 28 years old male and "Sunni Muslim". When I masturbate in my bed, after that I touch my pillow, books, wallet, mobile, door handle, mattress, room wall etc. with hands (with liquid semen). Even semen dropped so many times in my cloths, duvet etc. Even I touched many things with hands (after semen dried on the hand, without washing hands).

The clothes, which have semen on it (the semen is dried days ago), has No visible signs/stains. So, I cannot know exactly which spots in the cloths have semen. Do I have to wash these clothes before praying?

Some clothes have some visible signs or stains in some spots, and other spots in those clothes may have semen or not. In order to pray, do I have to wash it?

What about door handles, wallet, water bottles, mobile, laptop, room windows etc. that I touched when semen (dry/wet) was in my hands? 
The walls, door handles etc. doesn't show any visible sign (or no distinguishable signs due to semen), (it's true that I touched them with semen days ago). Do I have to wash these things?

If any object (pillow, bed cover, wall etc.) is touched ,with my dried semen or wet semen, and after some time there is no specific marks (or I cannot recognize any), do I have to wash them?
And, on them if I find any Mark (due to semen dried days ago), do I have to wash those objects? (Let's say, do I have to wash my mobile?)

I am very confused. In order to pray, what do I have to do?

For example: Yesterday I masturbated and didn't wash my hand. And after some time the hand became completely dry (I did NOT wash the hand, and there are dried semens and madhiy which are Not visible in the eye). If I touch any clean cloth with this hand, does the cloth get impure? And if I touch any object (laptop, mobile, door handle etc.), do I have to wash them?

Please reply bothers. Thanks for reading. 
I need a solution please.. ..

Answer (score 0):

Regarding semen (maniy), it is pure, so it is not obligatory to wash what has semen on it, yet it's better to do so.

But, it's obligatory to do ghusl after masturbating.

While madhiy is impure, so any cloth that has madhiy on it should be washed, and its enough to just sprinkle a handful of water on it.
And it's obligatory to do wudhu' after it.

And usually what comes out from masturbating is maniy, therefore it wouldnt be obligatory to wash what has maniy on it.
And if you were sure that what has come out was madhiy then you must wash whatever touches it ( regarding stuff used in prayer like clothes or the mat you pray on or so ) .

In the end, I remind you brother that masturbation is from what Islam has forbidden, may Allah cure you from this habit.

Comment: You said--- "And if you were sure that what has come out was madhiy then you must wash whatever touches it.". ....... For example-- madhiy has touched my laptop. How will I wash laptop?

Comment: You can clean it with a wet piece of cloth or some wet tissues.And that is also not obligatory. Someone asked about the purity of a bed after having intercourse with his wife, the mufti answered that you must clean it if it had madhiy and was used for prayer, but if it wasnt used for prayer (as the case for most people now and ofcourse your laptop) then it's just preferred but not a must. Our religion is simple bro, don't complicate things

Comment: And if you think that I'm contradicting myself by saying that you must wash whatever touches it; I meant clothes,  and I'm gonna edit it

Comment: So if madhiy touches laptop, wallet etc , do I have to wash it or not? And you said in the answer about sprinkle of water to wash a cloth (in case of madhiy).. Let's say, my shirt has madhiy on it everywhere, all the stains can be seen. Do I have to wash this shirt just sprinkling water on some spots of the shirt? Or, all the spots in the shirt? Or, do I have to wash the shirt completely with water (eg: washing machine) ? I am very confused .... Please reply

Comment: No, you don't have to wash your laptop since it's not used in prayer but regarding the wallet you might have it in your pocket during praying then you have to wash it, but if you dont have it on you during prayer, then you dont have to wash it. **Regarding your shirt, you should sprinkle water on spots which have madhiy on it** . If the whole shirt has madhiy on it *( which is fairly impossible )* then the whole shirt should be washed with water..washing machine isnt necessary

Comment: Are you "sunni" Muslim?

Comment: Yes, I am sunni